# Есть ли способ получить яндекс карты сделанные в конструкторе карт и выведенные на странице

Tags: yandex-maps-api, яндекс-карты

Задача изменять масштаб кары для мобильных, уже добавленных через конструктор карт. Но для этого карту нужно получить.

Comment: Уточните, сами ли вы создали карту, или чужая (есть ли доступ к исходнику). Опишите со скринами, что именно вы хотите изменить и в чём суть проблемы. Ссылки на ваш код и карту также приветствуются. В противном случае вам мало кто и чем сможет помочь.

Comment: Спасибо за участие. 
Вопрос такой, можно ли получить объект карты созданный из конструктора, для манипуляций. Нигде не нашёл информации по этому поводу. 
https://yandex.ru/dev/maps/constructor/doc/concepts/about.html?from=constructorapi
документация как-то скудновата.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Изменять объекты или масштаб карты [Конструктора](https://yandex.ru/map-constructor/) через его API, равно как и обратиться напрямую к карте и её объектам, невозможно. При сохранении карты в интерфейсе, её центр и масштаб фиксируются.

Если речь идёт о карте, которую вы создали сами, то объекты карты можно выгрузить экспортом. Подробней в [справке](https://yandex.ru/support/maps-builder/concept/markers_3.html).
В дальнейшем возможно отобразить на сайте карту с объектами из такого файла посредством JS API Яндекс.Карт. Пример есть в песочнице Яндекса:
https://yandex.ru/dev/maps/jsbox/2.1/object_manager_geojson

Comment: Спасибо, буду пробовать.